# DuplicateKeyException on the submitchanges method- Windows Phone

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am learning on how to insert data into the database using Linq and also to the ObservableCollection.
The data gets inserted into the ObservableCollection but not to the database. Could somebody explain whats going on with the code below. The system throws an unhandled exception on submitchanges method. Please advice.

```
public void populateDates(DateTime theWeek)
{
     ObservableCollection<theSchedule> theDatesList = new ObservableCollection<theSchedule>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        theSchedule theShift = new theSchedule 
        {
           theDay = (theWeek.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")),
           theTime = (theWeek.AddHours(i).ToString("HH:mm")) + " - " + (theWeek.AddHours(i+8).ToString("HH:mm"))
        };

        theDatesList.Add(theShift);
        //MessageBox.Show(theWeek.AddDays(i).ToString("HH:mm"));
        shiftsDb.theSchedules.InsertOnSubmit(theShift);
    }
    shiftsDb.SubmitChanges();
    mylistbox.ItemsSource = theDatesList;
}
```

Comment: So how are the key values generated?

Comment: The values are datetime variables converted to string. Here is the class that has the mapping table.

Comment: Temporarily move your submitchanges into the loop, debug an you will see what record is causing the duplicate key. Debug from there on

Comment: How do you generate these datetime key values?

Comment: Those are just C# DateTime variables. I just add to it and subtract from it to get the preferred date and time. Is it possible to post my project here, so that you could have a look at it. Thanks all.